# Why does Order by date asc is not working?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Good morning, I am trying to generate report based on the log_date where all records should be ordered from the latest to the oldest, I tried all the methods that I know and nothing works out, my code:

```
  SELECT
  LOG_DATE,
  FROM MY_TABLE 
  ORDER BY LOG_DATE ASC
```

and it will still order records from the oldest to the latest:

| LOG_DATE |
| --- |
| 17-JUL-19 |
| 29-JUL-19 |
| 29-JUL-19 |

where it should be:

| LOG_DATE |
| --- |
| 29-JUL-19 |
| 29-JUL-19 |
| 17-JUL-19 |

Comment: What **datatype** is the `LOG_DATE` column in your table?

Comment: @marc_s date datatype

Comment: Show us some sample data, both in the current order and the wanted order.

Comment: "and it will still order records from the oldest to the latest". This is what `ORDER BY log_date ASC` *is supposed to do* - the lowest, i.e. oldest, date first, the highest, i.e. newest, date last. If you want it vice versa use `ORDER BY log_date DESC`.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You show use `Desc` instead of `Asc`

The `desc` will show the latest to oldest